# Html inline div alignment issue

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="display:inline;  margin-left:10%;">
     <input type="radio">
     <span></span>
</div>

<div style="display:inline;  margin-left:10%;">
     <input type="radio">
     <span></span>
</div>

<div style="display:inline;  margin-left:10%;">
     <input type="radio">
     <span></span>
</div>
```

Hello I have a layout similar to the one above. I have some other things in the php file, but they are irrelevant. For example every new 5th element causes a new line (br), which will make sense when you see the pictures.

Here is an image representation of the outcome:

[image]

This is what I need :

[image]

How can I possibly do this, I will appreciate any idea. Cheers.

Note: Span tags contain the text next to the radio buttons.

Comment: Have you considered using a table?

Comment: Have you got any CSS styling that you have tried?

Comment: Margin left is the issue. The radio button tamam is having the margin left, what happens if you remove the margin?

Comment: Please if you can, use labels instead of (or with) the spans, with explicit linking. If this is going to face the open web, users like me will thank you! :)

Comment: Table will just give the same output as I  cannot use absolute positioning for dynamic growth of the parent div's size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iyi akşamlar :) you can remove div's, create class inside radio buttons and put them altogether into container for each row.

[**LIVE DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf57R/10/)

```
<div class="container">
         <input type="radio" class="radyo">
         <div class="text">a2</div>

         <input type="radio"class="radyo">
         <div class="text">a3</div>

         <input type="radio"class="radyo">
         <div class="text">a4</div>

         <input type="radio"class="radyo">
         <div class="text">a5</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
         <input type="radio"class="radyo">
         <div class="text">beyler ben geldim</div>

         <input type="radio"class="radyo">
         <div class="text">tamam</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Size de iyi akşamlar. Your jsfiddle example outputs the same problem doesn't it ?

Comment: Awesome, I will let you know if I was able to apply it to my case. Thank you.

Comment: Why though, how is it different?

Comment: Ah okay, the "width:100px" does it. But it makes it kinda unresponsive, yet its an ok solution, I will give you the mark mate.

Comment: Another problem, in my case, each div texts makes a newline which is expected, considering div is a block element. In your js fiddle, it does not make a new line. I am confused.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35796/discussion-between-ozum-safa-and-ali-carik)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid using inline styles.

If you want the result in the second image, simply define width for each element instead of margin.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:inline-block; margin-left:10%; width:15%;">
```

or set the margin-left and width as you see fit.

Comment: Oh no no, I am sorry, I see the point now. I cant understand how I could not think of this. Probably 50 hours of straight coding burnt my brain cells.

Comment: Ah ok, The problem is the div tag is not absolutely positioned and also the parent div tag is no absolutely positioned, which means I can not define absolute width. It just wont change the width at all. What do you think ?

Comment: I'm confused on your last comment.  You're saying that when you change that width value, it doesn't change the width?  It did for me.  Can you create a fiddle or show some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a nested div pattern, where you can utilize precised columns without margin/padding and insert a div that hold the margin/padding as desired.  Then push your checkboxes into each nested div.  I'd also suggest using a `<label>` over `<span>` (as it is a span with some extra properties)  ([MDN Label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label))

```
    .cols {float:left;width:25%} //Set columns up, without margin/padding so they align as expected in 4.

    .col {margin-left:10%;}  // Inner column with margin/padding etc.


    <div class='cols'>
       <div class='col'>
          <input type='radio' name='radio1' /><label for='radio1'></label> 
       </div> 
    </div>

    <div class='cols'>
<div class='col'>
          <input type='radio' name='radio2' /><label for='radio2'></label> 
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class='cols'>
<div class='col'>
          <input type='radio' name='radio3' /><label for='radio3'></label> 
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class='cols'>
<div class='col'>
          <input type='radio' name='radio4' /><label for='radio4'></label> 
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the width of your outer container, it would be easier for you to align fixed-sized divs inside it. For example if we have a div with `width: 300px;`, and we want 3 radio boxes on a row, we specify `width: 100px;` for them. Add `float: left;` and it should work out well for you.

[**Here's a live demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dcgnx/2/)

If fixed width doesn't suit you, there are many other approaches to do this, I can share if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Fixed does not work for me. At first I approached with a similar fashion. But % width does not work. Maybe it's because it's not absolutely positioned.